# execute code after typing indication over

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, chatbot

i have problem figuring out a solution . i am developing a chatbot .
this is my html where i print all the discussion , its just one :

```
<div  id="divChat">  </div>
```

i want to add typing indicator to it .here is how it works on each message:

1)User types his message (exemple : Hello), and click on a button

```
<button onclick="sendMessage()" id="btn1" > Send </button>
```

2) i read his message  and i sent it to mybackend application to receive the response and print it in the chat  element.

```
function sendMessage(){ 
var url = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/bots/renault/converse/user1";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
 if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var reponseBot= JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if(reponseBot!='undefined'){
     $("#divChat").append(reponseBot+"</br>");


    }
}
}
};
var values = {
   type: "text"
}
values.text=$("#userMessage").val();
var data=  JSON.stringify(values);
xhr.send(data);
}
```

the chat works fine , now i want to add typing indicator which is this  element (u dont need see css of it):

```
<div class="typing-indicator"></div>
```

i want When the user send his message i Append the typing indicator to the chat , show it for 2sec then hide it and append then response bot : like this

```
if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var reponseBot= JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if(reponseBot!='undefined'){

       $("#divChat").append("<div class='typing-indicator' ></div>");


           /// I WANT TO HIDE IT AFTER 2SEC THEN APPEND THE USER RESPONSE

        $("#divChat").append(reponseBot+"</br>");


        }
    }
```

Please any idea how to achieve this and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to delay an action.

Also note that if you've already included jQuery in the page you may as well use its AJAX methods to simplify the code. Try this:

```js
let $divChat = $('#divChat');

function sendMessage() {
  $.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/bots/renault/converse/user1', {  
    type: 'text', 
    text: $('#userMessage').val()
  }, function(response) {
    $('#userMessage').val(''); // empty the typed message

    let $indicator = $('<div class="typing-indicator"></div>').appendTo($divChat);
    setTimeout(() => {
      $indicator.remove();
      $divChat.append(response + "</br>");
    }, 2000);
  });
};
```

Also note that from the response to your AJAX request it looks like you're returning a plain text response which is not ideal, as it can be affected by whitespace. I'd suggest you amend your server side logic to return a serialised format, such as JSON or XML.